# How to complete this plotting task using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I tried this task but it didn't work and if anyone knows how to do it I would greatly appreciate it

Using the paradigm of iterative parallelism, calculate the value
functions () = ^3 + ^2 on the segment from 0 to 10. Specify the number of calculation steps
100.
Plot the graph of this function.

Below is my latest attempt at the task

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x_list = [x * 0.1 for x in range(100)]
y_list = []
for i in x_list:
    count = i**3 + i**2
    y_list.append(count)

xpoints = np.arange(len(x_list))
ypoints = np.arange(len(y_list))

plt.plot(xpoints, ypoints)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is taking the lengths here as mentioned in below two lines

```py
xpoints = np.arange(len(x_list))
ypoints = np.arange(len(y_list))
```

So fixed that up and you should be able to see the plot.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x_list = [x * 0.1 for x in range(100)]
y_list = []
for i in x_list:
    count = (i**3) + (i**2)
    y_list.append(count)

plt.plot(x_list, y_list)
plt.show()
```

[image: Your output plot]

Answer (score 0):

You only need this:

```
plt.plot(x_list, y_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

change `plt.plot(xpoints, ypoints)` to `plt.plot(x_list, y_list)`